# cassandra partion key grow limit?

Tags: cassandra

what means partions my grow large ? I think cassandra can handle a very large size of it. Why they use in this example 2 partion keys ?

And what I do maybe both partiton keys are too large ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example which you gave is one of the ways for preventing partitions to become too large. In Cassandra `partition key` ( part of primary key) is used for grouping similar set of rows.

Here in left side data model, `user_id` is the partition key which means every video interaction by that user will be placed in same partition. As mentioned in example comment, if user is active and has 1000 interaction daily then in 60 days (2 months) you will have 60000 rows for that user. This may breach Cassandra permissible partition size (in terms of data size stored in single partirion).

So to avoid this situation there are many ways you can avoid partition size to grow too big. For example, you can do

1. Make another column from that table a part of partition key. This is done in the example above. The `video_id` is made part of partition key along with `user_id`.
2. Bucketing - This is the strategy which is used in time series data generally where you make multiple buckets of a partition key. For example if `date` is your partition key then you can create 24 buckets as `date_1, date_2,.....,date_24`. Now you have divided your partition key into smaller partition keys and hence you divided one big partition into 24 small partitions.

The main idea is to avoid your partition to grow too big in size. This is a data modeling technique which one should be aware of while creating data model for Cassandra.

If still you have large partition size, you need to remodel your data model  based on various data modelling techniques available. For that I would recommend understand your data, estimate rate of growth, calculate estimated size of partition and if your data model is not meeting the partition size demand then refine your data model.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation! But if I use many partiton keys then this slow down the read performance. So if I have more and more then the reads are bad or  I am wrong ? And the second question: I only need a user id to query my data. If I use user_id and video_id as partition key then I have to query both data like this: SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 1 AND video_id = 1. But I dont need video_id as query parameter.

Comment: You are wrong with the assumption that with more and more columns as partition key will make your query slow.  Partition key is for grouping of your similar data. Also how to you want to query your data that will define your model. So if you want to query using userid, you can use it as partition key. But as I have mentioned if you start getting large partition then you may fall in problem in production. Design your data model such a way that you get your queries responses fast enough and you dont fell in trouble in future.

Comment: Maybe I have a solution to avoid partition key size on one partition. I add a uuid and after the uuid I add a  "+ " with 10 random characters. And If I want to check the userid take the user_id from my database and remove all characters after plus. So I avoid the large of parittion key is that good ?

Comment: You are close to solution but think about how will you create your partition key while querying. How will you know what uuid to append to your user id while querying your data.

Comment: With the Like statement uuid LIKE 'uuid%'